# How do I store a toggleable duration in a database

Tags: mysql, laravel, toggle, time-tracking

I want to give users of my Laravel Application the option to track the time they spend on different tasks. On clicking a "start" button, I want to create a new instance of a "tracking" object, which has an id and a reference to the task it is tracking the time for as a foreign key. Also, I want to store a timestamp from the second it was created on. Later, the user is supposed to stop the tracking with another button click.
I need to store the duration of the tracking somehow, because I want to give reports of what task had how many trackings, what was the total time of all summed up, etc. It would be an option to calculate the duration by subtracting start from stop, as soon as the tracking is being stopped and save it to the object.
However, I want the user to be able to continue a tracking later, so that it starts counting again. If I would then set the timestamp on ending again, it would calculate the entire duration, even though it could have been disabled inbetween.

Another idea was to have a last_started and a total_duration column. When the user (re-)starts a tracking, the timestamp is included. As soon as he closes it, the duration is added to the current total_duration and and last_started is set to null again. This feels like a dirty workaround and I am sure there are better options out there, which I would love to hear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague to me, but if I understand correctly, you just want ONE tracking record per task per user.  I don't see why you can't make it a bit easier.

Create a model TaskTimeTrack with

- user_id
- task_id
- starttime
- endtime

then in your controller, you should probably have a method `start` and `stop`

In your `start` method check if you have a TaskTimeTrack record for the user and the task and endtime IS NULL; if so, he shouldn't be able to start a new tracking, as he is still on an active tracking; just return the existing TaskTimeTrack (if you want to return anything)
If you don't find such record, just create a new one then.

In your `stop` method, just search for the TaskTimeTRack for the user and task where endtime IS NULL, and update the endtime to NOW.

there is no reason why you would want to limit just 1 record per user / task.  You just calculate the total time by sum(endtime - starttime) of all the TaskTimeTRack for a particular user or task or combination of both.